# Passing dynamic data to the construct of a service invokable

Tags: zend-framework2, servicemanager

I have the following `invokables` set in my application config

```
"service_manager":{
 "invokables":{
    "Dbmodel\\User":"Application\\DbModel\\UserModel",
    "Dbmodel\\App":"Application\\DbModel\\AppModel"
 }
}
```

So the theory is that I can call :

`$userMdl = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('DbModel\User');`

And the result will be an instance the class `Application\DbModel\UserModel`. OK This is great, that works I imagine now my question is this:

**In my user model I need to pass an integer to the `__construct` for an ID to load the model with database data**.

Clearly I cannot do this with having my models as invokables as I never get a chance to pass the ID.

**Is there a way to create a factory that you can `supply an argument such as a user id for my situation` to use with object instantiation.**

`An example would be using it in a controller to get a model based on a get request for a user based on id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea could be having a `UserModelFactory` retrievable from the service manager and use that to build, with a given method which takes the user id as parameter, the `UserModel` that you need

Comment: I like this solution